# Create nested menu using material-ui 4.9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the `@material-ui/core` library in my application and want to create a nested menu.  I can see that [material.io specification](https://material.io/components/menus/#) talks about a nested menu but `material-ui` does not have a built in support for the same. I tried using `Menu` and `MenuItems`. Also went through the documentation, but did not find the way to create such nested menu. Basically MenuItem is not allowing me to add children inside it. Can someone help me understand how to do this?

[image: a nested menue taken as a reference from the material.io specification]

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-nested-menu-problem-ibxoh

Comment: Please can (or in the future, remember to) add some of your code of what you tried to the body of the question, not just linking off to it. It makes it much easier for people to see what you've already tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not supported by `material-ui` officially yet. However, there is a package about it called `material-ui-nested-menu-item`, you can check how it works here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-nested-menu-item-example-b25j6

Comment: Could you provide some code examples in the body of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a package for MUI version 5.

[Material UI Nested Menu Item v5 on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-nested-menu)

[Material UI Nested Menu Item v5 Demo](https://mui-nested-menuitem-demo.vercel.app/)